# String Encodings IDNA -> UTF-8 (Python)

Tags: python, string, encoding, character-encoding

String encodings and formats always throw me.

Here's what I have:

'ไทย'

Which I believe is UTF-8, and

'xn--o3cw4h'

Which should be the same thing in IDNA encoding.  However, I can't figure out how to get python to convert from one to the other.

I was just trying

```
a = u'xn--o3cw4h'
b = a.encode('idna')
b.decode('utf-8')
```

but I get the exact same string back ('xn--o3cw4h', although no longer unicode).  I am using python 3.5 currently.

Comment: Are you using Python2 or Python3?

Comment: May I recommend http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html ? I found it invaluable for  anyone having trouble with Unicode in Python.

Comment: I'm happy to take any suggestions for good explanations on the topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To convert from one encoding to another encoding, one must first decode the string to Unicode, then encode it again in the target encoding.

So, for example:

```
idna_encoded_bytes = b'xn--o3cw4h'
unicode_string = idna_encoded_bytes.decode('idna')
utf8_encoded_bytes = unicode_string.encode('utf-8')

print (repr(idna_encoded_bytes))
print (repr(utf8_encoded_bytes))
print (repr(unicode_string))
```

Python2 result:

```
'xn--o3cw4h'
'\xe0\xb9\x84\xe0\xb8\x97\xe0\xb8\xa2'
u'\u0e44\u0e17\u0e22'
```

As you can see, the first line is the IDNA encoding of ไทย, the second line is the utf8 encoding, and the final line is the unencoded sequence of Unicode code points U-0E44, U-0E17, and U-0E22.

To do the conversion in one step, just chain the operations:

```
utf8_encoded_bytes = idna_encoded_bytes.decode('idna').encode('utf8')
```

---

Responding to a comment:

> I'm starting with isn't b'xn--o3cw4h' but just the string 'xn--o3cw4h'. [in Python3].

You have an odd duck there. You have apparently-encoded data stored in a unicode string. We'll need to convert that to a `bytes` object somehow. An easy way to do that is to use (confusingly) ASCII encoding:

```
improperly_encoded_idna = 'xn--o3cw4h'
idna_encoded_bytes = improperly_encoded_idna.encode('ascii')
unicode_string = idna_encoded_bytes.decode('idna')
utf8_encoded_bytes = unicode_string.encode('utf-8')

print (repr(idna_encoded_bytes))
print (repr(utf8_encoded_bytes))
print (repr(unicode_string))
```

Comment: but none of those actually spit out 'ไทย'

Comment: Right, because I am printing the `repr()` forms of the objects to make clear what they are. If you just want `ไทย` to appear on stdout, do `print (unicode_string)`.

Comment: I'm still missing something.  What I'm starting with isn't **b**'xn--o3cw4h' but just the string 'xn--o3cw4h'.