# How to handle UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, python-unicode, unicode-string

```
str1="khloé kardashian"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

how to encode it in perfect way.
I am trying to replace this in URL in flask app: It works well on command line but return above error in the app:

```
>>> url ="google.com/q=apple"
>>> url.replace("q=apple", "q={}".format(str1))
'google.com/q=khlo\xc3\xa9 kardashian'
```

Comment: ASCII does not have the character "é". What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Also, is this Python 2.7 or 3.x? Please specify, as they handle Unicode characters differently.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51710082/what-does-unicodedata-normalize-do-in-python

Comment: @Anwarvic that is because the browser handles the encoding details for you. See for example section 2 of https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986

Answer (score 2):

You should use `urllib` to construct the URL correctly. You have other issues in your URL, e.g., a white space. `urllib` takes care of them.

```
params = {'q': str1}    
"google.com/" + urllib.urlencode(params)
#'google.com/q=khlo%C3%A9%20kardashian'
```

Comment: In Python 3, the old `urllib` module was split up into a package, and `urllib.parse` has the relevant tools for handling URL contents (such as this). I fixed the code example accordingly.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The OP uses 2.7. Hence, the solution is for 2.7.

Comment: Oh, jeez. Just noticed that. Disappointed that this is still a thing (especially for a question that explicitly revolves around Unicode), but I guess I can't do anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

use utf-8 instead

```
str1="khloé kardashian"
str1.encode("utf-8")
```

Comment: ```>>> str1.encode("utf-8")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)```

Comment: make sure you deleted "str1.encode("ascii")" from your code

Answer (score 0):

A URL, per the standard, cannot have `é` in it. You need to use [the appropriate URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), which [is handled](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode) by the built-in `urllib` package.

Comment: There is a separate scheme called `idna` that is used to handle Unicode characters within the domain name, so that the browser can display Unicode to the user while sending something more old-fashioned to the DNS. This is also provided for in the `urllib` package. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41067320/string-encodings-idna-utf-8-python